# Bash command `find` with Regex pattern doesn't match correctly non-word-characters

Tags: regex, bash, find

I'm writing a Bash script and need to match all files and folders inside a directory which contain non-word-characters, uppercase-characters and German Umlauts. Inside my test directory I tried different combinations, but either I match any test file/folder or none despite the fact that it is working at Regex101 ([example 1](https://regex101.com/r/GwtqKB/1), [example 2](https://regex101.com/r/aytTrW/1)). I can't figure out if the problem are tokens/character classes i use or something Bash-specific:

```bash
$ ls 
kukukae.txt   KuKuKä.txt  'Replüce-?!% Test.txt.bak'   repluece_test.txt.bak  'Sä=?)(&%$§"!°^`´+*~#'   somo_oemo.gif  'Somo Ömo.gif'   super_  'why?that' # some example files and one folder
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '[^\w\.\/]' # nothing matched
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*[^\w\.\/].*' # matches also files without non-word-characters
./super_
./kukukae.txt
./Sä=?)(&%$§!°^`´+*~#
./somo_oemo.gif
./repluece_test.txt.bak
./why?that
./KuKuKä.txt
./Replüce-?!% Test.txt.bak
./Somo Ömo.gif
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '[[:upper:]]|[[:space:]]|[\?\&\ä\ü\ö\!\"\§\$\\\(\)\[\]\}\{\=\`\´\+\*\~\#\:\;\,\^\°\<\>\|]' # again nothing
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*[[:upper:]]|[[:space:]]|[\?\&\ä\ü\ö\!\"\§\$\\\(\)\[\]\}\{\=\`\´\+\*\~\#\:\;\,\^\°\<\>\|].*' # nothing one more time
```

It should look like the following, where only the files with non-word-characters and Umlauts are matched:

```bash
$ find [working command]
./Sä=?)(&%$§!°^`´+*~#
./why?that
./KuKuKä.txt
./Replüce-?!% Test.txt.bak
./Somo Ömo.gif
```

In both versions I don't want to match **/** or **.** intentionally (`[^\w\.\/]`), because it would include path and dots of file extensions.

Does any Regex-pro or Bash-veteran has an easy solution?

Thanks and best

Comment: `find` uses Emacs regular expressions by default, which doesn't recognize the `\w` escape sequence. Use the `-regextype` option to select a different regexp flavor.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, it's not even that standard; what you're describing is the GNU version of `find` -- the bsd version, on the other hand, defaults to POSIX "Basic" regex syntax (which is quite a bit different from all the other variants), and has a `-E` option to switch to POSIX "Extended" regex (and it doesn't have `-regextype` at all). So check the man page for `find` on your particular system to see what it uses. BTW, it also may or may not understand multibyte characters in bracket expressions (and escaping characters in bracket expressions isn't a thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a regex for this

```
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[!0-9a-z_.]*'
./Somo Ömo.gif
./Sä=?)(&%$§"!°^`´+*~#
./KuKuKä.txt
./Replüce-?!% Test.txt.bak
./why?that
$
```

Comment: Thanks @oguz, that was exactly the output i expected. The `LC_ALL` option was unknown to me.